# In dustjs, can I put a template inside a template, where the inner template is defined in partial tag with a string literal?

Tags: templates, dust.js

So I have an object like this {"templateName":"myTemplate","data":{"one":1}}

Here is my template:

```
{templateName}
{>"{templateName}":data/}
```

This does not render though (with no error message)...however, it works when I change it to this:

```
{templateName}
{>"myTemplate":data/}
```

It renders like this in the view:

```
myTemplate
[then here it shows myTemplate, rendered with data passed to it]
```

It renders perfectly and even shows the correct template name on top. I thought that putting the key in the quotes would work, but I guess I am misreading the dustjs guide. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a little digging, I believe I have found the problem. By using the syntax `{>"{templateName}":data/}`, you are changing the context from `root` to `data`. When this happens, `templateName` is no longer accessible when Dust tries to resolve the template name. So, Dust ends up searching for a template called `""`. I have filed an [issue](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/issues/383) for this bug.

Having said that, if I were to write a book called "Dust: The Good Parts", I would leave contexts out of it (e.g. `{#myData:myContext}`). I have found that they cause more problems than they solve.

As a workaround, you can use this syntax:

`{templateName}
{>"{templateName}"/}`

And then your "myTemplate" would need to do something like:

`{data.one}`

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4Qc8r/) of this working.

Comment: Great answer...I guess this means I could also put my templateName in the data object. It's funny to know that there are dust.js experts out there.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for what template engine I should use if I really need to use contexts galore?

Comment: Dust does a great job of switching contexts, just not with the colon notation. If you want to switch contexts, you can use `{#data}{one}{/data}` instead of `{data.one}`.

Comment: Sorry...I'm still getting used to the terminology. I am not merely changing the context...I am dynamically changing the template, so I need to use the colon notation. Because this is broken, my templates are complicated and it largely defeats the purpose of using templates.

Comment: For example, say I have multiple types of objects and I want to represent the data in each of the object types in its own way (by its own template), but I also want to represent the data of these objects in the same location on the page depending upon if the mouse is hovering over one type of link or another. What better way to accomplish this than to use dynamic templates?